# Socket.connect() connects but no serverSocket listening

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Another road block in my attempt at TCP holepunching. 
My server is sitting behind a NAT and I am looping a call to socket.connect() to a mobile phone's NAT'd public IP.

On my mobile phone I press a button to run a socket.connect() to the server's NAT'd public IP. The mobile phone says it connects to the public IP and port of the server. But the server doesn't seem to realise this.

If I run a serverSocket on the server instead of the socket.connect(), the mobile phone isn't able to connect.

This is confusing me to no end. Why would the mobile phone call to socket.connect() succeed if there is no serverSocket listening?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code on the mobile phone app.

```
try {
        Log.d("stop", "line 64");

        Log.d("stop", "line");
        Log.d("localHost: ", myIPAddress.getHostAddress());
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
        Log.d("stop", "line 70");
        clientSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        clientSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
        Log.d("stop", "line 72");
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIPAddress.getHostAddress(), serverPort), 15000);
        Log.d("connected", clientSocket.toString());



        //BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
        //receivedMessage = inFromClient.readLine();
        Log.d("stop", "line 78");


        //globalSocket app = (globalSocket)getApplication();
        //app.setSocket(clientSocket);
        commsock = clientSocket;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "socket caughyt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        error1 = "no Server";
        Log.d("error", error1 + e.getMessage());

    }
```

This is the whole loop on the code from my server app.

```
    while(true){

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        try {

                System.out.println("105");
                mobileSocket2 = new Socket();
                mobileSocket2.setReuseAddress(true);
                System.out.println("109");
                //mobileSocket.setReusePort(true);
                //mobileSocket2.setSoTimeout(50);

                mobileSocket2.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
                System.out.println("bound");

                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("caught 104: " + e.toString());
                }


        try{

                System.out.println("124");
                System.out.println("connection made 29: " + mobileSocket2);
                mobileSocket2.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mobileAddress.getHostAddress(), mobilePort),5000);
                System.out.println("connection made 239: " + mobileSocket2);



            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("exception 2 caught " + e.toString());
                mobileSocket2.close();


            }



    //}//end of while   
} // end of main
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use in your server code the **accept** methode :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29

Comment: I used the Resource Monitor (perfmon) in Windows and the connection from the mobile phone has definitely made it to the laptop. The TCP connection is listed there under java.exe.

But for some reason, serverSocket.accept just says "accept timed out". No idea why. I put it in the loop as well, but didn't accept anything.

Comment: There might be two reasons behing the timeout issue : The firewall is preventing the connection or you're connecting the phone on the wrong port. I think that the issue comes from the firewall.

Comment: but if its the firewall why does the resource monitor say the tcp connection has been made? or can the firewall block the tcp connection after its been made?

Comment: What I can suggest is that when you use the accept method, you put the socket returned as a parameter in a thread class than implement the code you need in the run method of the thread class that you would have created.

Comment: as in the accept method doesn't return a socket at all. it causes an exception that it timed out (cause there was nothing to listen to for some reason)